# Several Xamarin.Forms Android activities

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to use several Android activities. First is general application. Second is notification view. They have different activity settings and therefore I can't use one activity for this issue.

I try to do this:

```
[Activity(Label = "Life Manager", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        ActionBar.SetIcon(new ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent));
        LoadApplication(new TimeManagerApplication());

        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5), OpenNotificationActivity);
    }

    private bool OpenNotificationActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
}

[Activity(Label = "NotificationActivity")]
public class NotificationActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen | WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new NotificiationApplication());
    }
}
```

In this line:

```
LoadApplication(new NotificiationApplication());
```

I take an error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How can I use two android activities in one application and use cross-platform Xamarin.Forms views for it?

**Update:**

Without these lines application perfectly works:

```
//RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
//Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen | WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```

But how can I hide status bar and use fullscreen view?

Comment: Why you don't use the same activity ? When you recieve the notification you just navigate to the correct view.

Comment: @Eastrall, please keep attention to the different settings of activities. I need fullscreen and state without status bar with Notification view.

Answer (score 0):

I decided this issue.

To take Fullscreen view without status bar is enough use only Window Flags

```
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen | WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```

without:

```
RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
```

Application works as expected without exceptions.